# Reactjs set selected date value at Datepicker

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to set selected date to Datepicker from state but this showing invalid date format error here is my code, I am update the date state from axios which is working fine  and I got date value at react dev tools

state

```
this.state = {          
        product: {             
            date: '',             
        }
      
    }
```

render

```
<DatePicker autoComplete="off" className={'ks-form-control form-control'}
                                                selected={new Date(this.state.product.date)}
                                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                name="date"
                                                isClearable
                                                placeholderText="Select Date"
                                    />
```

error

```
RangeError: Invalid time value
```

Comment: What date do you put there?
https://reactdatepicker.com/   please see the examples, mb your format incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial value of the `this.state.product.date` is empty `''`
and when you try to get a date out of it it's a invalid date

```
new Date('') // Invalid Date
```

So you should do something like this

```
...selected={this.state.product.date ? new Date(this.state.product.date) : new Date()}...
```

Comment: Glad that helps  you